# LASTDATE Function with Criteria / Days Since Percentage Achieved

Tags: excel, dax

Please help.

I am trying to use DAX to find out the number of days since a percentage has been achieved.

Currently I have been playing around with the LASTDATE function and adding a criteria. However, the error message I get is that you cannot add more than one arguement.

I have tried using calculate but still no luck. Example below;

```
=CALCULATE(LASTDATE(Testtable[Pct. Test]),FILTER('Testtable',[Pct. Test]>74.5))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LASTDATE` function needs to be on a date column. It looks like you are trying to calculate the last date in the `[Pct. Test]` column.

Comment: Thanks @Alexis Olson. Changed it to

=CALCULATE(LASTDATE(Testtable[Date]),FILTER('Testtable',[Pct. Test]>74.5)) 

However, it returns blank cells.

Comment: Should it be 74.5%, i.e., 0.745 instead?

Comment: Bingo I thought because the percentage column was formatted as a percentage it'd match the format. Thank you!

Comment: I know you answered the previous question @Alexis Olson but without creating a new one i'd like to take it one step further. With the current formula it will look at the date column and Pct. Test and outline when the last 74.5% or greater was achieved for all dates / all individuals. However, i'd like it to look at each row / name individually. I have another column Testtable[Name]. Is there a way to get it to look at each row in isolation?

Comment: I'm not quite following. I think you should open a new question for that.